# Is there a way to build a web page that uses different fonts on a phone screen and a desktop screen without writing any JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm familiar with coding but I have severe time constraints and would rather not revisit Javascript for this issue. Any suggestions on how I can cut down the effort needed to load the different fonts? Much appreciated thanks!

Comment: How do you define "phone screen" and "desktop screen"?  And, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Yes. [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can do it in CSS, using @media rules to set different fonts based on the screen size. Here's a good source of information: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices.

I'd set the desktop font first, then override it with @media queries with your phone font.